# Get full path to folder in another project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi i have solution with many projects in my mvc3 application
One of the projects is console. And i need to get full path to upload folder in web project from this console.
How i can do this?

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("~/Content/Upload"); //return wrong path...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, best way is to put a key in your console app's app.config of the full path of your upload folder.

Comment: I was try it. But this is Controller service. Server not recognized in console application :(

Comment: This will only be valid in the context of a web request, otherwise you'll get a HttpException.

Comment: So it no way to get path to folder from console?

Comment: @Strillo My bad, I didn't read the question properly, updated it anyway.

Comment: @user1086344 you are in different project means different context. Why don't you want to keep the full path in app.config? It's customizable anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the path of a web application from a console application just because they are part of the same solution.

`Server.MapPath` only works in the context of a web server and requires a web request to validate and determine the root directory.

You probably need to review your design, or, for instance:

1. store the folder details in a config or shared file, registry key or database
2. pass it as a parameter to the console app
3. modify the web app to provide a web service and then call it from the console application

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Strillo but solution could be easy if you use web application App_Data path pysical folder in console application which is defined in app.config. And all applications try to reach same folder.

Comment: Can you give me example of how i can write path in app.config?

Comment: you can manage your config in different files. and you should define them in your main app.config as  <appSettings configSource="App_Data\Configs\AppKeys.config"/>
<connectionStrings configSource="App_Data\Configs\Dev\Databases.config"/>